# List being cleared when used Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have been using Python 2.7 for a couple of weeks and need some help on the loop below:

```
nos_rounds = raw_input("Number of rounds?")
student = stu_input(ui)# links to a function to input a list of strings 


for x in range(0,int(nos_rounds)):
     student2 = randomList(student)#randomising list function
     student2 = partition(student,gs)#partitions the randomised list
     fcprint(student2)#prints the student list to the console and a file
```

The  problem I am having is the second time the loop runs the list 'student' is cleared out and made in to an empty list. 'student' is not altered at all by the code. What is going on here? I am new to coding and can't seem to work this out. Any help would be much appreciated!

functions requested are:

```
def randomList(a): # this creates a random list of students on the course
    import random
    b = [] 
    for i in range(len(a)): 
        element = random.choice(a) 
        a.remove(element) 
        b.append(element) 
    return b

def partition(lst, n): # this creates sub list of the student list containing the groups of students
    increment = len(lst) / float(n)
    last = 0
    i = 1
    results = []
    while last < len(lst):
        idx = int(round(increment * i))
        results.append(lst[last:idx])
        last = idx
        i += 1
    return results

def fcprint(student):#print to the console and then to an external file
    floc = raw_input("Input the name of the file")
    f = open(floc +".doc", "w")
    for item in range (0,len(student)): 
        print ""
        print "Group",item+1, ":\n", "\n".join(student[item]) 
        print >>f, "\n"
        print >>f,"Group: ", item+1
        print >>f, "\n".join(student[item])

    f.close()
```

Thanks, I tried the below:

```
for x in range(0,int(nos_rounds)):
    newstu = student[:]
    print "top", newstu
    student2 = randomList(newstu)# randomises the student list student is reconised on the first run but is empty on second run
    print "bottom", newstu
    student2 = partition(student2,gs)# creates the groups

    fcprint(student)#prints the student list to the console and a file
```

Still can't get it to work. Output is for print statements:

```
top ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
bottom []
```

Got this to work with the excellent advice of the forum . Working version is:

```
def randomList(z): # this creates a random list of students on the course
    import random
    r = z[:]
    b = [] 
    for i in range(len(r)): 
        element = random.choice(r) 
        r.remove(element) 
        b.append(element) 
    return b

for x in range(0,int(nos_rounds)):
    student2 = randomList(student)# randomises the student list student is reconised on the first run but is empty on second run
    student2 = partition(student2,gs)# creates the groups
    fcprint(student2)#prints the student list to the console and a file
```

Comment: what is `randomList`, `partition` and `fcprint`? Most likely you mutate your list in one of these functions.

Comment: Could you post the code for `randomList()` and `partition()`?

Comment: You need to provide source of randomList() & partition() functions to get an answer. Also it's not clear from your code what is the "gs" parameter that is passed to partition().

Comment: Certainly your functions are updating your list. That's a beginner error. Read [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at randomList():

```
def randomList(a): # this creates a random list of students on the course
  import random
  b = [] 
  for i in range(len(a)): 
    element = random.choice(a) 
    a.remove(element) 
    b.append(element) 
  return b
```

At this line `a.remove(element)` you remove elements from the original list until it's gone. So on 2nd iteration it will be empty.

By [@loutre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059760/loutre): Try doing a copy of your list (e.g a_copy = a[:] and work with this copy inside the function

Comment: Yes you right a print statement above and below the calling of random_list for a list of string numbers equals above  student = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] and below - student =[].

Comment: So if i answer your question please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks I tried some code (added to the original post) still can't seem to get this right.

Comment: @SilverMerlin of course, you did exactly the same thing with the `newstu` list ! Try making a copy *inside* the `randomList` function, and work with it

Comment: And why not to use random.sample()?

Comment: Yes that works thanks @loutre and Alexander Trakhimenok. The penny has dropped! I've got the code working now. As you say it needs to be in the function before the function loop.